# JavascriptSerializer, Deserializer, not able to deserialize my object

Tags: c#, .net, json

I am unable to deserialize my custom object.

```
public class UserInfo
{
  public int Id1 { get; set; }
  public string Code { get; set; }
  public int Id2 { get; set; }
  public List<string> Roles { get; set; }
  public string Eg1 { get; set; }
  public DateTime Time{ get; set; }
  public string Eg2 { get; set; }
  public string Version { get; set; }
}

JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

return serializer.Deserialize<UserInfo>(raw);
```

The Deserialize is throwing an exception

"Cannot convert object of type 'System.String' to type 'UserInfo'"

JSON Contents:

```
"\"{\\\"Id1\\\":0,\\\"Code\\\":null,\\\"Id2\\\":0,\\\"Roles\\\":null,\\\"Eg1\\\":\\\"Eg2\\\",\\\"Time\\\":\\\"\\\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\\\/\\\",\\\"Version\\\":\\\"1.0.0.0\\\"}\""
```

*Note: Let me know, if it is unclear. I'll edit the question.*

-- edited. ID2 changed to Id2. The real class is different in terms of variable names. Hence the issue.

Comment: Surely there aren't all those \'s in the JSON! Make sure to put the *actual [JSON] text* in the post, not the inspector-what-if-this-were-a-string-literal value .. if this was done it *would be obvious* that the *text* value is `"json junk which is in a string and not a JSON object"`.

Comment: Thanks ... Seems i was on sleeping pills. When I looked at it I was serializing twice! hence unable to re-cast. It is working now. Updated the correct JSON.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are passing a Javascript string to your deserializer because you have your object within an escaped string.

After unescaping it, this is what the serializer receives:

`"{\"Id1\":0,\"Code\":null,\"Id2\":0,\"Roles\":null,\"Eg1\":\"Eg2\",\"Time\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"Version\":\"1.0.0.0\"}"`

What you really want to send it is:

`{"Id1":0,"Code":null,"Id2":0,"Roles":null,"Eg1":"Eg2","Time":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/","Version":"1.0.0.0"}"`

Answer (score 12):

Your string is a C# string containing a JavaScript string containing JSON. Short of fixing what you're being sent, here's how you would deserialize:

```
var jsonString = serializer.Deserialize<string>(raw);
return serializer.Deserialize<UserInfo>(jsonString);
```

Comment: Thank you! I have been looking for a method of approach this clean. I never thought of the type casting to string prior... Works like a charm

Comment: This will not work. string does not have a parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ID2` is all caps in the JSON and the `Id2` is not in your class.

### EDIT:

Try creating an instance of the object and serialize it to JSON to compare and see if the JSON is correct or not. You can then use that string to properly format.

Answer (score 0):

The code below should help someone get up and running.

the above code will cause an error on  because string has no default constructor.
If a string is passed in from JSON.stringify() client JavaScript method the second Deserialize may work if the object passed in maps to the public fields in the  object.

Let's look at a quick example presuming an .ASHX file receives the request from a jQuery call that looks like this:

```
//Called from with a jQuery ready() in a simple html page

var getNewPerson = function ()
{
var NewPerson       = new Object();
NewPerson.PersonID  = "0";
NewPerson.FirstName = $("#FirstName").val();
NewPerson.LastName  = $("#LastName").val();
NewPerson.Address   = $("#Address").val();
NewPerson.City      = $("#City").val();
NewPerson.State     = $("#State").val();
NewPerson.Zip       = $("#Zip").val();

var arrObj;
var str = "";
var webMethod = "http://someserver.com/admin/DataHandler.ashx";
$.ajax({
cache: false,
url: webMethod,
type: "POST",
dataType: "json",
 /* for hashtable or .net web service -  data: "{\"NewPerson\":" + JSON.stringify(NewPerson) + "}", */
data: JSON.stringify(NewPerson), 
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
}
)
.done( function(){}... code here ...etc)

//Valid JSON object format: {"PersonID":"1","FirstName":"Rick","LastName":"Wright","Address":"4520 No Such address Ave.","City":"Riverside","State":"CA","Zip":"92503"}

//And here is a sample class on the C# side in the .ashx handler page.
public class NewPerson
    {
        public int PersonID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Zip { get; set; }
    } //  EOC Person
```

// And in the process request

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
string jsonString = "";
string rawJson = "";
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
string responseString;
var jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
/*Set the stream position to 0 */
context.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;

using (System.IO.StreamReader inputStream = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream))
{
rawJson = inputStream.ReadToEnd();
}
var objNewPerson = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<NewPerson>(rawJson);
if (clientList != null)
{

responseString = objNewPerson.FirstName + " " + objNewPerson.LastName ;
}
else
resp="No Record Found";
} // eof ProcessRequest
```